# Request permission dialog isn't appear Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions

I'm trying to get a `Write_external_storage` permission at the beginning of app work. But I can't see permission box. Here is my code:

```
override fun onStart() {
        .....

        if (Singleton.isPermissionGranted(this)) {
            btn_submit_t.isEnabled
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 1)
        }
        super.onStart()
    }
```

and then I added `onRequestPermissionsResult`:

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        when (requestCode) {
            1 -> {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.i("m","permission_is_granted")
                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied to read your External storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Handler().postDelayed({
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                            if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                //your permission is granted

                            } else {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 1)
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            //permission is automatically granted on devices lower than android M upon installation
                        }
                        //ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 1)
                    }, 100)

                }
                return
            }
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    }
```

I tested it on different devices, and my problem appears on Xiaomi device with Android 6.0.1 version. I also added checking but it didn't help me. Where can be the problem?

Comment: It might be button enable disable issue

Comment: @Piyush, is it a your question or a suggestion?)

Comment: Suggestion......

Comment: yes, I would like to enable/disable btn, but I can't see any permission boxes anyway and it is strange for me :(

Answer (score -1):

Have u added "WRITE EXTERNAL STORAGE" permission in Manifest File?